# Tengo una función recursiva con PHP que no me funciona

Tags: php, array, funcion

Tengo un problema con una función.
El objeto de la misma es recibir un array de enteros, ver si hay enteros repetidos, cambiarlos y volver a comprobar. El código queda así:

```
function corroborarArray($lot){
    $nuevo = array_values(array_unique($lot));
    $longitud = sizeof($nuevo);
    if ($longitud < 10){
        for($i = $longitud; $i < 10;$i++){
            $nuevo[$i] = rand(1,15);
        } 
        corroborarArray($nuevo);
    }
    
    return $nuevo;
}
```

Por alguna razón no me funciona. Por favor alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! llamas a la funcion.. pero no te quedas con lo que devuelve....

Comment: Parece que quieres obtener un arreglo de 10 números entre 1 y 15 sin que se repitan. Hay mejores formas de lograrlo sin tener que involucrar recursividad... incluso, sin ciclos. Basta con crear un arreglo con los posibles números, [desordenar](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.shuffle.php) y, finalmente, [obtener la cantidad de elementos deseada](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-slice.php).

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que debes hacer es agregar una flag  `SORT_NUMERIC`

El código quedaría de la siguiente manera

```html
function corroborarArray($lot){
    $nuevo = array_values(array_unique($lot,SORT_NUMERIC ));

    $longitud = sizeof($nuevo);
    if ($longitud < 10){
        for($i = $longitud; $i < 10;$i++){
            $nuevo[$i] = rand(1,15);
        } 
        corroborarArray($nuevo);
    }
    
    return $nuevo;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, acabo de probar lo que me dijiste y el problema persiste. Siguen apareciendo números repetidos en la serie.